# How to display start time and end time of a task in Nant script?

Tags: time, nant, task, trac, execution

I want to check how much is the execution time of my each taks. How to display execution start time and end time in nant script.

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to the beginning and end of your tasks:

```
<echo message="The current date is: ${datetime::now()}" />
```